# First column not appearing

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}  % flush-left, not justified
\newcommand\mC[2]{\multicolumn{1}{L}{#1}}
\sisetup{group-four-digits=true} % show thousands separator for 4-digits numbers

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}    % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\caption{Funding round}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} 
    S[table-format=4.2] c l L *{2}{S[table-format=5.2]} @{}}
    \hline
    
     {\bfseries Name of the Shareholder} & 
    \bfseries No. of Equity Shares & 
    \mC{\bfseries Percentage of the pre-Offer Equity Share Capital on a fully diluted basis (\%) } \\
    Percentage of the pre-Offer Equity Share Capital on a fully diluted basis (\%) \\
    \hline
    Go Digit Infoworks Services Private Limited & 729565220 & 83.65 \\
    A91 Emerging Fund I LLP & 29282949 & 3.36 \\
    TVS Shriram Growth Fund 3 & 31066389 & 3.56 \\
    Faering Capital India Evolving Fund II & 18638596 & 2.14 \\
    Faering Capital India Evolving Fund III & 10644353 & 1.22 \\
    Wellington Hadley  Harbor  AIV Master  Investors (Cayman) III, Ltd. & 13024841 & 1.49 \\
    SCI Growth Investments III & 9054878 & 1.04 \\
    Total & 841277226 & 96.46 \\
    \hline
    *Based on the beneficiary position statement dated August 12, 2022.  &       &  \\
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document containing your table. Also please test this document, if it is compilable.

Comment: The code I posted is compilable. On another post I asked how to fit a table that was too wide. The solution I got instructed me to use tablularx and line breaks. So I tried replicating what was done in that piece of code on this table.

Comment: Sorry, it is not. Missed are `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` ...

Comment: oh sorry let me edit it. This code is a snapshot of a larger document

Comment: You declare 5 columns, but populate only three. In the first column (`S` type) you have only text, so it can't be compiled.  Please, can you provide an sketch of desired table?

Comment: Hey I've added the sketch

Comment: Sorry, but the screenshot you posted is from the answer I provided to your earlier query. The screenshot's table has six columns, but the new code has only 3 columns.

Comment: basically I want the cell with long text to be wrapped

Comment: Hm, your code for table is not even close to showed table.  Where is correct content: in image of table or in (erroneous) table code?

Comment: please fix your question it makes no sense to post the code from one document and ann unrelated image from something else. Your code stops at `! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number 'D'.`

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you posted appears to be quite unrelated to the table code you provided.

I'd say that in addition to allowing line-breaking in all cells of column 1 and in the header of column 3, you should also arrange for a line break in the header of column 2. I'd further suggest that you not **bold-face** the headers, as it's quite distracting. Maybe something like the following, then:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % flush-left, not justified
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{} C @{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\textbf{No.\ of Equity}} % determine intended width of 2nd column

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\caption{Funding round\strut}
\label{tab:addlabel}
%% define a table with three columns:
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L p{\mylen} S[table-format=2.2] @{}}
\hline
\bfseries Shareholder & 
\bfseries No.\ of Equity Shares & 
\mC{\bfseries Percentage of pre-offer equity share capital, on fully diluted basis, in \%} \\
%%\mC{Percentage of the pre-Offer Equity Share Capital on a fully diluted basis (\%)} \\
\hline
    Go Digit Infoworks Services Private Ltd. & 729565220 & 83.65 \\
    A91 Emerging Fund I LLP                  & 29282949  & 3.36  \\
    TVS Shriram Growth Fund~3                & 31066389  & 3.56  \\
    Faering Capital India Evolving Fund II   & 18638596  & 2.14  \\
    Faering Capital India Evolving Fund III  & 10644353  & 1.22  \\
    Wellington Hadley Harbor AIV Master Investors (Cayman) III & 13024841 & 1.49 \\
    SCI Growth Investments III               & 9054878   & 1.04  \\
    Total                                    & 841277226 & 96.46 \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{\small *Based on beneficiary position statement dated August 12, 2022.}  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks. Also would you please recommend me a source on how to import tables from excel into overleaf for all types of scenarios? My job consists of importing tables frequently and I'm facing a lot of trouble and end up spending a lot of time for a single table. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As starting point for table in image shown in the question. For it I would use `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\sisetup{group-four-digits=true} % show thousands separator for 4-digits numbers

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \small
\caption{Funding round}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {@{} S[table-format=4.2] c l 
                            X[1.9, cmd=\RaggedRight] 
                            X[1,c,si={table-format=5.2}]
                            X[1.1,c,si={table-format=5.2}]
                            @{}},
             row{1}  = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
             row{1-2}= {guard}
             }
    \toprule
Amount
    & Round
        & Stage
            & Investor
                & Pre Money Validation
                    & Post Money Validation     \\
(INR Cr)
    &   &   &   & (INR Cr)    
                    &   (INR Cr)    \\ 
    \midrule
417 & 8 & Growth-PE
            & IIFL VC, Sequoia Capital India
                &   & 30 496        \\
1001.82
    & 7 & Late
            & Wellington Management, Fearing Capital, TVS Capital, Others
                & 29 971.97
                    & 26 072.97        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```